# there was an error creating the child process for this terminal . operation timed out

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 stop working and every thing get lazy, actually It didn't freeze I can navigate but everything become very very slow after some time of training a Bert model. When I open a new terminal I got this

**there was an error creating the child process for this terminal . operation timed out**

Even restarting the system take ages.
This error arises after some time of deep learning training

Comment: Watch memory and processor use using `top`. Could be a problem caused by extraneous memory use (too few memory, or the app managing memory badly, i.e. mamory leak).

Comment: actually none of them is the issue, GPU memory is 8 GB and I limited it to 6. Same with  ram. Some time the whole system run flawlessly then same code gave error

Comment: Well, if not the ram, then the processor use - certainly something is abnormal with your program.